# can change chang startup periority?

Tags: c#-4.0

i have a windows application and register it in windows register to start up automatically when windows starts.

it requires to get some information to start working and get themes from internet .

it works fine but if it start to works before network interface initializing this case a problem because can not retrieve necessary information to start working.

i want to know is that any way to change windows start up priority that programs or others like internet connection can works and initializing by that?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to check if a network connection is available, and if not, wait until it is before starting the network-dependent part of your program.

To check if a network connection is available: [System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getisnetworkavailable.aspx)

To be notified when a network connection becomes available: [System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkchange.networkavailabilitychanged.aspx)